# Model Predictive Control gives always zero output solution - Why? Do I need soft constraints?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, model-predictive-control

I have a discrete state space model:

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k)$$
$$y(k) = Cx(k)$$

And I'm trying to compute the predicted inputs. The first thing I do is that I fist create the extended observability matrix $\Phi$

$$\Phi = \begin{bmatrix}
CA\\ 
CA^2\\ 
CA^3\\ 
\vdots \\
CA^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then create the lower traingular topelitz matrix
$$\Gamma = \begin{bmatrix}
CB & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
CAB & CB & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
CA^2B & CAB & CB & 0 & 0\\ 
 \vdots  & \vdots  &\vdots  & \ddots  & 0 \\ 
CA^{n-2} B& CA^{n-3} B  & CA^{n-4} B & \dots  & CA^{n-j} B 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $j=n$

Then I use linear programming:

$$max: c^TU$$
With subject to:
$$KU \leq O$$
$$U \geq 0$$

Where $K = \Gamma^T \Gamma$, $c = (\Gamma^T\Gamma)^T(R - \Phi*x)$, and $O = \Gamma^T(R - \Phi*x)$ and also $R$ is the reference vector and $x$ is the state vector, and $U$ is our input signal vector. We want to find that! That's our goal.

**Problem:**

Assume that our state space model is not 100% correct identified, then $R - \Phi*x$ can be negative due to $\Phi*x$. Which leads vector $U = 0$ because linear programming want to maximize $c^TU$ and $U$ cannot be negative.

**The result:**

This prediction gives only $U = 0$ if my model is not 100% correct identified.
How can I solve this, so even if my model is not 100% correct identified, $R - \Phi*x$ can never be negative e.g $R - \Phi*x \geq 0$

This comes from a practical experiment.

**Edit:**

The reason why I'm using linear programming (Simplex method) is because it's simple and easy.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to solve in words? The optimization problem you are trying to solve is really strange and the issue might just be that the formulation is wrong.

Comment: It is unusual, i think, to use a linear cost function (as opposed to the classic quadratic cost function) in MPC because of the very problem you encounter. I imagine you could introduce the constraint $R-\Phi x \geq 0$ into the linear program but all that will do is make it very obvious when you have an inconsistent system. The most natural solution is to change your cost to be quadratic and solve the quadratic program (or use off the shelf solutions like Fast MPC). I predict this is not your desired solution?

Comment: @Rollen the reason why quadratic optimization is used is because quadratic gives a smoother inputs and linear programmering is more deadbeat control. Both works, but for mechanical systems, quadratic programming is prefered. Bit for temperature controlled systems, linear programming can be used.

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve this is not a bad way to solve an optimization problem. It works, only if you have a very good model.

Comment: Could you constrain the system identification such that the linear programming does not run into this problem?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen constrain the system identification? How? I'm using Recursive Least Square for this SISO identification. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid/blob/master/sourcecode/rls.m

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I know the issue now. Kalman matrix K will cause instability. Don't know why. I thougth RLS could estimate a kalman gain from a first order ARMAX model.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen But that does not change the topic of the question.

Comment: I need to reformulate the optimization constraints. But how?

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, but the first thing came to my mind was KU<=O and U>=0 leads to U=0. But, then I saw this is O and not 0. Very confusing. Hope you did not similar mistake while coding.

Comment: @Arashium solution = add integral action.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, than for updating me.

Comment: @Arashium I have tried to implement this onto an embedded system. Seems to be a very bad controller. PID-controller seems to work much better than MPC. Also I suggest AI is much better than MPC as well.